# Getting Id 'undefined' in Jquery Datatable in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am getting undefined message alert when I am trying to fetch the Id of the particular row by jquery datatable.

Here is my latest code,

```
<table id="gv_Datatable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Receipt</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Receipt</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="Plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "FillGridMethod.asmx/GetCashBookList",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var datatableVariable = $('#gv_Datatable').DataTable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',      
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'Id', visible: false },
                        {
                            'data': 'cashbookdate', 'render': function (date) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                            }
                        },
                        { 'data': 'cashbookaccname' },
                        { 'data': 'cashbookreceipt' },
                        { 'data': 'cashbookpayment' },
                        { 'data': 'cashbookdescription' },
                        {
                            "render": function (data, row) { return "<a href='#' id='" + row.Id +"' class='btn btn-success' onclick=DeleteCustomer(this); >Delete</a>"; }
                        }]
                });             
            }
        });

    }); 
    function DeleteCustomer(obj) {
        var rowID = $(obj).data("Id");
        alert(rowID);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the **GetCashBookList** Method (which call from the ajax url)

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetCashBookList()
{
    var cashBook = new List<CashBookModel>();
    string constr = cn.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        qryFillGrid = " select cashbookid, cashbookdate, cashbookaccname, cashbookreceipt, cashbookpayment, cashbookdescription from tbl_cashbook ";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(qryFillGrid, con);
        con.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var cashBookModel = new CashBookModel
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                cashbookdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1]),
                cashbookaccname = dr[2].ToString(),
                cashbookreceipt = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[3]),
                cashbookpayment = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[4]),
                cashbookdescription = dr[5].ToString()
            };
            cashBook.Add(cashBookModel);
        }
    }
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(cashBook));
}
```

Comment: What data do you get from `FillGridMethod.asmx/GetCashBookList`?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen edited the question please review it.

Comment: I see the method but have you verified that you are actually getting the data you expect?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Yes I am getting the accurate data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the render function takes 3 parameters (data, type, row).
Then you only need to know the `Id` of the data you want to delete.

With these two points we can change the code of the render function to

```
"render": function (data, type, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-success' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + row.Id + "');>Delete</>";}
```

and the `DeleteCustomer` function to:

```
function DeleteCustomer(id) {
  // Do your thing...
}
```

I've created a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3g1ncuv/1/) as demonstration.